# Eclipse C++ Project with nested folders

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, directory, eclipse-cdt

I'm relatively new to C++; I know the syntax and stuff, but not much about the compiling part. I made a project using Eclipse, and it's gotten relatively big. So before I continue on, I want to put related files together in a subfolder. Currently all my files (source and header) are in `src/` (like `src/Foo1.h`, `src/Foo1.cpp`, etc.), and I would like to sort it something like:

```
src/
 -> Foos
     -> Foo1.h
     -> Foo1.cpp
     -> Foo2.h
     ...
 -> Bars
     -> Bar1.h
     ...
 -> main.cpp
 ...
```

However, I would also like to have the includes be relative to the src folder (and the current folder too, if possible). For example, I would like `Foos/Foo1.cpp` to be able to include things like:

```
#include "Foos/Foo1.h"
#include "Bars/Bar1.h"
```

or,

```
#include "Foo1.h"
#include "Bars/Bar1.h"
```

I feel like this should be possible, but I'm afraid I don't know enough about C++ compilation or Eclipse CDT to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your paths /src and /src/Foos etc to the list of Include Paths and Preprocessor Symbols

For me it is under Project Properties -> C/C++ Include Paths and Symbols

Comment: Hmm... Works good enough for me, but just one side note: it allows `#include Bar1.h` rather than forcing it to be `#include Bar/Bar1.h`.